# Tmp Copy of initial values [of global Array]

Tags: java, arrays, copy, global

I am working on a program, where I have to constantly change the values in my global array.

In one method I need to make use of a copy of this global array, but the copy should only include the first initial values of my global array (so the copy should not change values like the global does). 
Can anyone help me how to initialize such a tmp array?

```
int[][] copy = int [][] global;
```

wont work.

Comment: `int[][] copy = int [][] global;` is not Java code. What should it do? And what do you mean with "initial values of my global array" ? You can't go back in time and get values that aren't there anymore of the array was changed in the meantime.

Comment: In general the global array is a map which i will scan first by each column and then by each line. If I get an object and several conditions apply e.g. in the  global[2][1] I move this object to another (random) place. Nevertheless if this objects moves to the next field ( global[2][2] ) I will scan the same object again which is what i want to avoid. Therefore I want a copy of the global array where nothing has been moved yet. Then I can scan the copy and only move objects in the global array.

Answer (score 0):

You need deep copy.

If your array contains simple types (eg. int):

```
static int[][] global = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] copy = new int[global.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < global.length; ++i) {
            copy[i] = Arrays.copyOf(global[i], global[i].length);
        }
    }
```

If your array contains complex types (some objects), one of the ways is a copy constructor:

```
static class Foo {
        private int x;

        public Foo(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public Foo(Foo other) {
            this.x = other.x;
        }
    }

    static Foo[][] global = {{new Foo(1), new Foo(2)}, {new Foo(3), new Foo(4)}, {new Foo(5), new Foo(6)}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo[][] copy = new Foo[global.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < global.length; ++i) {
            copy[i] = new Foo[global[i].length];
            for (int j = 0; j < copy[i].length; ++j) {
                copy[i][j] = new Foo(global[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey lukas, 
thanks for the idea. 
The problem is also that I am not allowed to use my main and only work from a given method which is linked to the main. 
I could of course do the same in a "help-method" but since the program is interactive ( with recursion ) I guess I will get a new copy ( with also new values ) for each step in my program.

Comment: Provide some code because so far I don't know what the problem really is. In my examples global array is not going to be changed - it is a static array which you can access from any method.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post anything public, since I have to hand this code in for university and they will check for plagiarism with some kind of searching tool for the web.

Comment: You don't have to paste the code you are working on but some example that describes the problem you have. If I understood corectly: _so the copy should not change values like the global does_ deep copy is the answer and I gave an example above so you should know how to use if you have basic programming skills.